# XSL Sort by position() giving weird results

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I have an XML file whose contents I want to sort by document order (basically in the order that the items were written out).

I currently use the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="/Error">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Error/Warning">
<!-- etc -->
</xsl:template>
```

Example XML (data replaced for ease of reading):

```
<Error>
<Warning data="stuff" timestamp="08:26:17 2010/08/01">CODE.1</Warning>
<Clear data="stuff" timestamp="08:26:36 2010/08/01">CODE.2</Clear>
<Warning data="stuff" timestamp="08:36:00 2010/08/01">CODE.3</Warning>
<Clear data="stuff" timestamp="08:36:56 2010/08/01">CODE.4</Clear>
<Warning data="stuff" timestamp="08:40:31 2010/08/01">CODE.5</Warning>
</Error>
```

This, however, seems to give odd results as it seems to be in no particular order! Any ideas?

Removing the sort seems to make it work properly - will this reliably order it in write-order or is that not guaranteed?

Comment: You don't provide the problematic output and you don't explain what is wrong with the output that you have not shown. Also, you don't specify what really needs to be sorted. This question is incomplete and undefined. Please, correct your question.

Comment: It looks like your pattern is wrong, it should be `ErrorLog/Warning`. Also you are sorting in document order, so there is no need for that.

Comment: @Dimitre The output is just in a random order, I didn't feel it important to show that? - Updated question so that it is clearer

@Alejandro I want to order everything within `<Error>`. Paul Butchers response below works fine for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsl:apply-templates />` operates over the selected nodeset in document order, remove the sort element, and this will work as desired.  See: [Applying Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules)

Answer (score 1):

arent you missing what nodes you want to apply an template to?

for instance:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/Error/messages" />
```

would be nice to have the xml you are working with when dealing with a xslt issue.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like this? using the select attribute on apply-templates?

```
<xsl:template match="/Error">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./Warning" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Error/Warning">
  <!-- etc -->
</xsl:template>
```

You should get the output in the order it is in the XML source.

Comment: @Chris  If you want to filter the children of Error, and only have Warning elements, it is better to use `xsl:apply-templates/@select`, as defined in this answer, than to just use `xsl:template/@match`